# rebuild a plot giving an image

Tags: pgfplots

I don't know if this is the right place where to post this request. It could be weird but I will do my best to explain it. The pic below shows two plots. What I would like to make is to recreate them using pgfplots. How can I do that? is it possible?

[image]

Comment: To answer only your last question: I'm quite sure that it is possible as the graphs aren't really difficult.

Comment: yes, should be easy enough- do you have the data?

Comment: @cmhughes No unfortunately I have not the data. This is the real problem

Comment: So to clarify: you want to reproduce the graphs above without the underlying data? Then you should first try to extract the data from the graphs, the rest should be rather easy. There are some tools on the web that are more or less able to do the data extraction job automatically. Just ask your favorite search engine.

Comment: @Mazzy [Tools for digitizing data from an image of graph or plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converting_scanned_graphs_to_data). Its all approximation. I used [digitizeit](http://www.digitizeit.de/) and `Techdig` in our lab research, which are shareware.

Comment: The real problem is to have the data. Having the data the problem is resolved...

Comment: Since the problem is about getting the data, this seems a little off topic for tex stack exchange- unless someone has a way to ask `TeX` to try :)

Comment: Extracting data from existing graphs is as mentioned above not on topic for us: I've therefore closed. Of course, ADP's answer might still help in your particular case :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO You should digitize the data first, use a package like http://getdata-graph-digitizer.com/ or one of the millions of free applications that allow you to do this.

These applications, you basically define the axis, define the values of the extremities, and then click points along the series to as much detail as you need. Easy Peasy.

Once you have the point data, your question is simply one of plotting.

Comment: That program you suggest me it is great...I got all data...Thanks so much!!!